# Swift - How to create a function that will pick random gestures

Tags: ios, swift, gesture, picker

I am having trouble creating a random gesture picker that will pick a random gesture when called. I was thinking of creating a random number picker and then set each gesture to a specific number, then checking if that is the right gesture that the user performed. Is there a way to set a number to a gesture, like how you can on buttons? Is there a better way to do this? How would I go about doing this? Thanks!